# Delphi: Convert a TByte into its corresponding Hex-Value in AnsiString

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, byte, hex

I'm trying to output the value of a TByte as its corresponding hexadezimal representation in an AnsiString.

Example:
TByte is 0x4F
AnsiString: "4F" (two characters, a 4 and an F)

I know of the StringOf function, but that converts to the "mapped" character.

Is there any decent function build in or does somebody has a good idea how to implement this fast?

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: Is `TByte` something new in Delphi 2010, or it is merely a typo?

Comment: Sorry, like I wrote in my comment to the original answer, I assumed that the basetype of TBytes is TByte, but it is just "Byte". I'm sorry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd cast it to a Byte and feed it to SysUtils.IntToHex.

Comment: Yey it works :D Thank you, I just noticed that it wasnt TByte but a "Byte", so I could feed it as it was.

Answer (score 0):

The Format Function has been present since Turbo Pascal days and the SysUtils Hex functions were not available.

So for any version of Delphi before D2010, use the format command:

```
lByteAsHex := format('%.2x',[AByte]);
```

The .2 Precision specifier ensures that there is always leading zeros.

The following line:

```
lIntAsHex = format('%x',[AInt]);
```

handles any size integer (including int64) but will not put leading zeros, so
`format(%x,[10])` will return 'A' whereas `format('%.2x',[10]` will return '0A'